# The code cannot be compiled

Tags: c, syntax

```
void Input(int arr[100])
{
    int index;
    printf("Enter the array\n");
    for(index = 0; index < 100; index++)
    {
        printf("Enter %d number\n", index+1);
        scanf("%d", &arr[index]);
    }
}

int minValue = 32767;
int index;
int sort;
for(a = 0;a < 100;a++)
{
    if(arr[a] < minValue)
    {
        index = a;
    }
}
for(a = 0;a < (sizeof(arr)) / 4;a++)
{
    index++;
    arr1[a] = arr[index];
}
for(a = 0;a < (sizeof(arr1))/4;a++)
{
    for(index = a;index < (sizeof(arr1))/4;index++)
    {
        if(arr1[a] > arr1[index])
        {
            sort = arr1[a];
            arr1[a] = arr1[index];
            arr1[index] = sort;
        }
    }
}
for(a = 0;a < (sizeof(arr1))/4;a++)
{
    printf("%d\n", arr1[a]);
}

int main()
{ 
    char choise = '0';
    int loaded = 0;
    int arr[100];
    do
    {   
        printf("---------------MENU----------------\n" );
        printf("- 1.Enter array -\n");
        printf("- 2.Use already entered array -\n");
        printf("- Space for exit program -\n");
        printf("-----------------------------------\n" );
        scanf("%c", &choise);
        if(choise == ' ')
        {
            printf("Bye Bye\n\n");
            return 0;
        }
        switch(choise)
        {
            case '1':
                Input(arr);
                loaded = 1;
                break;
            case '2':
                break;
            default:
                printf("You have entered an invalid value\n");
                break;
        }
        if(!loaded)
        {
            printf("You haven't enter an array yet.Please choose 1 first.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            magic(arr);
        }
    } while(choise != ' ');
    return 0;
}
```

Hello this is my first c project and i have some syntax erorrs i tink and it cant be compiled ? Please explain to me where are my erorrs ?

I use Visual Studio 2010 to write my code.

Also the directives that i use are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

This is the erorr from the compiler:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Georgi, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Georgi.cpp
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(14): warning C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\stdio.h(304) : see declaration of 'scanf'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(20): error C2059: syntax error : 'for'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(20): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(20): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(20): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(20): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(20): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(20): error C2086: 'int a' : redefinition
1>          c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(20) : see declaration of 'a'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(20): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(21): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(21): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(27): error C2059: syntax error : 'for'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(27): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(27): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(27): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(27): error C2086: 'int a' : redefinition
1>          c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(20) : see declaration of 'a'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(27): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(27): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(27): error C2086: 'int a' : redefinition
1>          c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(20) : see declaration of 'a'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(27): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(28): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(28): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(32): error C2059: syntax error : 'for'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(32): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(32): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(32): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(32): error C2086: 'int a' : redefinition
1>          c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(20) : see declaration of 'a'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(32): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(32): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(32): error C2086: 'int a' : redefinition
1>          c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(20) : see declaration of 'a'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(32): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(33): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(33): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(44): error C2059: syntax error : 'for'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(44): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(44): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(44): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(44): error C2086: 'int a' : redefinition
1>          c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(20) : see declaration of 'a'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(44): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '++'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(44): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(44): error C2086: 'int a' : redefinition
1>          c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(20) : see declaration of 'a'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(44): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(45): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(45): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\users\alexievpc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\georgi\georgi\georgi.cpp(84): error C3861: 'magic': identifier not found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: paste error produced by the compiler also ...

Comment: I have paste the erorrs from the compiler.

Comment: I recommend that you let the Visual Studio editor indent your code for you. (Press Ctrl-k, Ctrl-d to indent the entire document.)

Comment: If this is your first C project, you should start with the bare minimum and add one line at a time, making sure each new line still compiles without errors. Don't write 100 lines of code and then act confused when the compiler explodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using statements outside a function ( `for(a = 0;a < 100;a++)` up to `int main()` ). This is not legal C.

The function `magic` is not known to the compiler -include the proper header file or add its declaration/definition to the compiled source.

Also note that your code neither declares `a` nor `arr1`, the latter possibly needing memory allocation as well (looking at the compiler messages, though, the declarations just aren't contained in the code fragment you posted).